# How can I get current time of autoplayed html5 mp4 video in javascript and then stop it when time reaches for lets say 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

So, I need to autoplay couple of videos with same class on page load. That is fine.
Then, when videos starts playing, when they reach for 1 second, I need them to stop automatically. The other part is what I need.

```
 <video playsinline muted loop class="video">
     <source src="video-source">
 </video>

let videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   videos.forEach(el => {
    el.play();
   });
 });
```

I have tried doing something like this, get currentTime and then make an IF statement but no luck. It always console loggs 0.

```
  function myFunction() {
   videos.forEach(el => {
   console.log(el.currentTime);
   if(el.currentTime = 5) {
   el.pause();     
  }
});
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you will have with your current attempt is that it only runs once, you need to have a way of checking your logic at intervals so that you can continuously check the time lapsed.

You could potentially look at using the [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) video event, this runs repeatedly whilst a video is playing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will take a look into this.